# Is Eventual consistency incompatible with user authentication process?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I practice DDD in my project.

Let's assume the boundedcontext **IdentityAndAccessContext** and **MeetingContext**.

Both contexts deal with the following terms:

- **IdentityAndAccessContext** has the notion of `User` class.
- **MeetingContext** has the notion of `Participant` class. (let's forget `Creator` for the example).

`Participant` represents the **user** in **Meeting** bounded context.

First, a `User` has to be created, leading to a `UserCreatedEvent`.
Then, in order to apply eventual consistency between those bounded contexts, the message is stored in the IdentityAndAccessContext and then sent helps to an event listener and message queuing (still in the IAC context) to the **MeetingContext**, in order to create automatically the corresponding `Participant`.

It sounds like a good DDD design (IMO), however I come across an issue with this webapp's workflow:

- User is registering through a registration form and he's redirected to the home page.
- The home page needs some `Participant` values...and that's the issue:
  **The process of eventual consistency might not finish before the redirection to home page, leading to "no values".**

**How to deal with this case?**
Making the user wait before a notification of consistency? Bad UX no?
Inserting the `Participant` values in the same transaction of the `User`? ... violating Bounded contexts concept, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is User created when forwarding to the Home Page?

Comment: @Hippoom Yes, `User` is created BEFORE the home page is loaded

Comment: A tricky one is: redirect to the homepage with values needed and display them if the participant is not ready. The participant should be ready when the user logs in next time. :-)

Comment: @Hippoom I wish it would be so simple :)  The thing is that home page depends on a database query that involves `Participant`'s bounded context, no `User`'s one...

Comment: @Hippoom What if I force the registration process to be longer than enough by slowing down the rendering to user just after the `UserCreatedEvent` was stored (in order to give high probability that `Participant` is created? Only the registration would be impacted, and registration happens only once. I really don't know the best practice..

Comment: Or maybe other solution => My authenticating controller currently does three things: handling the registration command, querying for the registered user (separated to follow CQS) and returning the result to the user containing an access token. I think about adding a step just before the return, implementing a loop aiming to check that the Participant in the MeetingContext is well created before returning result to user. It will involve a communication using REST interface or RPC from the IdentityAndAccessContext to the Meeting bounded context.

Comment: Good idea, you could insert an advertisement over there and polling to detect if the participant is ready just like @Eben Roux said : D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would recommend is to design your UI with the eventual consistency in mind.  Let's say you owe your ISP $10.  You go into your online banking site and perform an EFT.  You log onto your ISP account page but your payment does not reflect.  In this scenario it sounds almost silly to expect the money to reflect immediately.  Eventual consistency is expected and chances are you would either click a 'refresh' button till the funds reflect or simply wait a day or two for the transaction to reflect since that is the expectation.

I don't think that you should ever try to create an interactive system using messaging since it is asynchronous by nature with no real deterministic outcome w.r.t. timing.  However, you could track the registration process in the 'source' bounded context and, therefore, know that the message has been sent and report it as such on, say, the participant page; something like: 'Your participation request is in process'.

Then using either some form of polling or server-based push technology you could update the participation page once the participant object is ready.

It could sound overly simplistic but I still think one should aim to design with the uncertainty in mind.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought about this solution, dealing with a kind of http pushing (like websocket). I asked the same question into a famous google-group and had a solution dealing with immediate consistency. I really think that it would be more UX to deal with immediate consistency in this case, what do you think? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/_Ic80BqTtfg

Comment: However immediate consistency would lead to include the MeetingContext dependency into the IdentityAndAccessContext. So would alter the reusability property of IAA context...

Comment: To sum up, I prefer your solution :) Thanks a lot !